# Gatling not able to write to graphite influxdb

Tags: graphite, gatling, influxdb, grafana

I have some gatling test to write it into influxdb using graphite protocol. The tests run fine, not able to see the results sent to influx via graphite protocol. my gatling.conf file looks like below,

```
data {
        writers = [graphite]
    }
    graphite {
      host = "10.xxx.xx.xxx" 
      port = 2003          
      protocol = "tcp"
      bucketWidth = 100
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to see what is been sent to graphite(influxdb) and how we can check the data in influxdb?

P.S: Running the gatling test using gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to your InfluxDB instance using the InfluxDB CLI

```
$ influx -host 10.xxx.xx.xxx
> use graphite
```

The issue the query

```
> SHOW SERIES
```

you should get a list of all of the [series](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/concepts/glossary/#series) in your instance.